# UI Label Appears off the View Controller

Tags: autolayout

When ever I check to see how my page will look in landscape mode and then switch back to portrait mode, one of my UI labels flies off the screen. Pic below:

[image]

I have to bring it back, then I clear the constraints and then click "reset to suggested constraints" and it looks to be set in place but keeps changing by itself.

**EDIT:**
Below is picture of my constraints which xCode set up automatically for me with "Reset to Suggested Constraints". The label that is going off the screen is called "Last Reported"

[image]

Comment: Please show the constraints  you have applied

Comment: Added constraints to original question

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue and it seems like and Xcode interface builder issue. The Layout in interface builder is not updated as expected, but running the UI on actual device works as expected.

Still one expects, while developing on interface builder, the view to be mimic the way it would behave on real device. And adding/removing constraints every time the orientation changes is pain.

Since this does not happen in the above case, and **the layout is not updated**, we can force the layout update on interface builder, by

1. Editor > Update frames. ('option' + 'command' + '=')
2. Change the constant value of any of the constraints applied and revert it back.

For this case the second option, updated the layout.